# Error in the R.Java file

Tags: java, android

I tried to run some code and in doing so, the following file opened up when I clicked on the play button: R.java

This is a screenshot of the error:

[image]

As you can see on the left hand side, the clas "EditStock" has no space, but in the R.Java file it does. I'm not sure why and I'm not sure how to fix it.

I've tried to clean and rebuild the project but to no avail.

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: Try invalidate cache/restart option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

R.java is generated from the resources in the `res` subfolder. The `id` class is generated from elements of XML layout files. In one of your XML layouts, you have `android:id='+@id/Edit Stock'`. You need to change it to `android:id='+@id/EditStock'`. The .java files are irrelevant to this error.

Answer (score 0):

`R` gets generated from your resources. Most likely the problem is in some layout that has a space in an `android:id` attribute.